# Trouble with .htaccess RewriteRule (mod-rewrite)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't seem to get the RewriteRule to take affect - it just isn't matching.

My url: `http://www.example.com/users/username/articles/2012/03/12/article-title.php`

My .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^users/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/articles/$ article.php?url=/users/$1/articles/$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RewriteRule you listed only captures URLs that end with "articles/". You need to add something to capture the rest of the text, like (.*), giving you

```
RewriteRule ^users/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/articles/(.*)$ article.php?url=/users/$1/articles/$2 [L]
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! This rule will keep the original URL displaying in the browser, for all browsers, correct? (a "hidden" re-direct)

Comment: Yes. Also, you might want to change [L] to [L,QSA] to keep any additional query string that the application adds.

Comment: Another relative rewrite in per-directory context without `RewriteBase`. Apache should fix this pitfall.